# typedef in C for struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

If I have a struct such as:

```
typedef struct bag {
  int test;
} *bag;
```

Then if a function consumes bag. Let's say:

```
int sample(bag *b) {
    b->test ...
}
```

I get the error that I made a request for member 'b' in something that is not a structure or union. How do I fix this? I could cast b to a (struct bag *) but that seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just defined the type `bag` to be a *pointer* to the type `struct bag`.  Thus, when you make a variable of type `bag *b`, you are effectively creating a variable of type `struct bag**`.  Either change your argument to be `bag b`, or do a double dereference for your member (`(*b)->test`).

**Edit**
As another poster mentioned, you probably meant `typedef struct bag { ... } bag`, then your original code will compile.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide: Either bag is the name for a *pointer* to the struct, or bag is a name for the struct: Probably you meant

```
typedef struct bag {
   int test;
} bag;
```

Then your code compiles.